# How could I remove the watermark on my homepage?

Tags: jquery, html, css, page-flipping

I have buy a program, which calls FlippageMaker. I have build my Flippage, but as I want to publish, there was the watermark and I couldn't remove it. I have searched for the watermark, I have founded in Google Chrome under Ctrl+Shift+J in ... So I went to my HTML Editor, Synwrite, but I couldn't find it. Sorry for my English, I'm from Germany. Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="monitor-signature" content="monitor:player:html5">
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

<meta name="Keywords" content="" />
<meta name="Description" content="index" />
<meta name="Generator" content="FlipBook Creator Professional 2.3.5  at http://www.flippagemaker.com" />
<link rel="image_src" href="files/shot.png">
<meta name="og:image" content="files/shot.png">
<meta property="og:image" content="files/shot.png">
<title>index</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile/style/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile/style/player.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile/style/phoneTemplate.css" />

<script src="mobile/javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="mobile/javascript/config.js"></script>



</head> 
<body>
    <script src="mobile/javascript/bookmark_config.js"></script>
<script src="mobile/javascript/LoadingJS.js"></script>

    <script src="mobile/javascript/main.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile/style/template.css" />



    </body>
    </html>
```

And here the Screenshot:

[Scee.Watermark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prSxsds1.jpg)

I hope you can help me! Thanks

Comment: It might be generated on the fly. Any JS files accompanied?

Comment: If you *bought* the program that should have been removed when you entered the *licence* details...no?

Comment: Search in the JS files `config.js, main.js, LoadingJS.js and bookmark_config.js` for `demo.png` and see if you get any hits, if yes simply remove the line that shows the watermark

Comment: I have searched in all js files, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just go here mobile/style/icon/demo.png and open file in photoshop or in another photo editor remove that folder photo and save it again as png 24 with transparent background. the photo will be in style but empty.

Comment: Thanks! I try, but what is with the text.